# RVM why don't gems install to locally to project folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rvm, bundler

So here's my problem:

I have a project and I am trying to install Gems locally to that project. For example if I install devise from the Gemfile and then run a bundle install it won't put any of the controllers in the controllers directory of the project. Instead I have to hunt through the RVM directories to get that particular gem's controllers, copy them to my project and then start writing my project from there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Bundle shouldn't install gem code into your applications code. In the case of Devise, it's controllers, views, models, and whatever else will stay in the gem itself. If you need to override something, like a view, Devise has a build in generator that will drop the views into your app `rails generate devise:views`. Gems are there to isolate library code from your own. Is there a reason you need to access Devise's controller? As a rule of thumb you shouldn't be changing Devise's code directly.

Comment: So for instance the users_controller that is supposed to come with the Devise installation isn't supposed to be in my application controller then? That's weird...

Comment: Yep, that's correct. If you set up your routes correctly, and have Devise installed correctly, it'll know what to do and it's Users controller will do it stuff. It does not need to exist directly in your app.

Comment: Thanks Shane! I appreciate it...I just didn't understand, still new to rails and I sort of get it, but not all the way. I have done php in the past, but this is a bit different.

Comment: No problem. I was very new to programming when I first started with Ruby/Rails. Admittedly gems confused me as well. Just hang in there. Good luck.

Comment: I find it very easy to understand, more so than php, just because it does do a lot of the work for you. I know that there are MVCs on php but they are a pain in the ass to work with compared to rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comment above answered your question - when you add a gem like Devise to your app, it doesn't generally drop code directly into your application. Sometimes it provides a generator which will install some parts of it, but mostly it alters config files so that the code in the gem gets pulled into your app when it starts.

You can ask bundler to install gems in the "vendor" subdirectory of your app, instead of in the main RVM/Ruby location, with the `--path` option. But you usually only want to do that for production deployment, not development.

Comment: Ok...so if I want to deploy this to a remote server, I would do a bundle install --path and then it would package all of that up for me? That's pretty nifty. I was just concerned, I am new to rails, it seems really easy, but then at other times it seems relatively complicated. Thanks for the help really appreciate it!

Comment: That's right, and it is nifty. ;) Just run `bundle install` and Bundler will take care of all your dependencies, whether you're on the server or developing locally. If you're running more than one app on a server it'd be wise to look into adding RVM as well to keep them nicely isolated.

Comment: `bundle install` will install your dependencies in the default location -- deep within RVM in your original question. `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` puts them all in that directory in your project. Makes for a good way to keep gems separated between different apps on the same server.

Comment: Peter, I am just going to be deploying one app to a server...probably with a lot of Gems. I really didn't understand why things were happening the way that they were. Like I said I am relatively new to rails and so forth, so it was a bit scary! =)